# How important is a correct Bundle Identifier

Tags: xcode, bundle-identifier

I created my Xcode Project a while ago with a bundle identifier of `com.CompanyName.ProjectName`. But at the time I didn't have a domain. Now that I do, it is `CompanyName.ca`, because `CompanyName.com` was already taken. But, I have created an app record, and already submitted the build of the app version with the incorrect bundle identifier to iTunes connect. Obviously my Bundle Identifier is "incorrect".

My question is whether having this "incorrect" bundle identifier will create problems due to `CompanyName.com` being taken, and whether it is ok to submit more applications with a bundle identifier of `ca.CompanyName.ProjectName` instead of `com.CompanyName.ProjectName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse DNS notation recommended for bundle ids does not directly translate to the kind of URLs you enter in your web browser. What matters is that the bundle id in your app's Info.plist and the one you entered in iTunes Connect match. That is how your app is identified and cannot be changed once a record for an app has been created (on iTunes Connect). 
In any case there is no need to be fearful that there might be some sort of 404 error because your reverse DNS doesn't "point" to the correct domain. That is not going to happen. As for future titles, it would seem best that you DO use the correct reverse DNS notation. Just as a matter of convention.